How should religious Jews (and Noahides) respond to these criticisms
I’m curious how the community here would recommend responding to these criticisms of the claim that God exist: https://youtu.be/ExBsyaiRYW4?feature=shared. To summarize (although please for anybody who doesn’t have YouTube completely blocked, watch it yourself and try and formulate a response), his argument is twofold: he claims that since God’s nature involves infinity, omnipotence, omniscience etc., God can’t exist because of the metaphysical axiom of the law of identity (his philosophical tradition is Objectivism, the philosophy of Ayn Rand). Second, he formulates that God isn’t possible because he asserts God is absolutely arbitrary, there is no evidence for it and since there is no evidence there is no demonstration of possibility, if one can’t even demonstrate something is possible how can one reasonably believe in it? After all, why should one believe in invisible goblins on Venus who read Mark Twain books if there is no evidence for that? I believe in God, however I would appreciate community input.

His claim seems to be that there is no proof for G-d's existence. The majority of arguments for G-d's existence are centered on finding proof for it, and he didn't respond to any of them. He basically didn't present any argument at all.

Btw, Rabbi Tovia Singer once made a good point. Noahide as a term is nice, but really, they are following the religion of Judaism, as non-Jews. Perhaps the best way to phrase the title would be "how do followers of Judaism..." or even simpler, "how does the Torah respond..."

The speaker is making a few assumptions, and appears to admit that is because he is presupposing the truth of objectivism, and its atheistic implications, i.e. that there is lack of evidence for God, and there are metaphysical contradictions. I would say that he has a very left-brained, rational mind, and therefore views everything logically/rationally and materialistically. Therefore, ultimately, he can't conceive of God because he has no clue about how to apply his intellect outside of the limitations of logic.
He may not realise it, but he thinks that God must be some sort of object, and when he follows the logic there, he arrives at contradictions. However, not only does Torah not presume that God is an object, but also makes theological conclusions about God that this gentleman's line of thinking would consider "impossible" or contradictory.
The Law of Identity proves that God doesn't exist
False witness. The Law of Identity only disproves a God if God is meant to obey the law, but why should He? He does not have to follow any rules given that He created the rules themselves!
As I said, God is not an object or category.
All of the "logical paradoxes" from applying the law of identity to an infinite or undefined being are true regarding God. We do assert that He is indistinguishable from nothing, to us, in the sense of "yesh m'ayin"; something from nothing. In fact, we apply this principle to the entire spiritual cosmos, and then declare that God is exalted above even the spiritual cosmos, so how much more so does this argument not apply to God.
To put it in terms of greek philosophy, the argument being made in the video assumes that all is corporeal. The rule of identity applies in the corporeal sense that two different objects can be identical, and still exist independantly. In the spiritual cosmos, there is no corporeality, only form. If two forms are identical, they wouldn't be two, but would be the same. However, to be identical, they need to have a property or description, and would thus be composite. This does not apply to God, who cannot be composite. See Moreh Nevuchim 1 and 2 for the full discussion, who dealt with this by tackling the greek philosophy, and see Maharal, Gevurot Hashem, Hakdama 2 for the general philosophy of Torah on this theological point:

אבל הוא יתברך שקראו רז"ל בשם "הקדוש ברוך הוא", ולא נקרא "השכל ברוך
הוא", כי אמיתת עצמו לא נודע, רק שהוא נבדל מכל גשם וגוף ומכל הנמצאים,
ועל זה נאמר "קדוש ברוך הוא", שענין "קדוש" נאמר על מי שהוא נבדל, כי הוא
יתברך פשוט בתכלית הפשיטות. ומזה בעצמו שהוא בתכלית הפשיטות, אין דבר
נבדל ממנו, כי הדבר שיש לו גדר ומיוחד בדבר מה, בשביל אותו גדר נבדל ממנו
דבר שאינו בגדרו. אבל מפני כי הוא יתברך פשוט ואין לו גדר כלל, אין דבר
נבדל ממנו. ואם כן, הוא יודע הכל, והוא יכול הכל, וכל זה מפני שאין לו
גדר יוגדר בדבר מיוחד, ובשביל זה הכל נמצא מאתו גם כן
Our sages, of blessed memory, refer to Hashem as "the Holy One,
Blessed be He" and not "the Intelligent One", because the truth of His
being is unknown, except that He is separated from all forms of
substance and body that can be found. This is why they call Him "Holy
One Blessed Be He". The term "holy" denotes an entity that is apart
and removed, and Hashem is simple in the most ultimate sense of
simplicity. But precisely because Hashem is the ultimate simplicity
(abstraction), there is nothing that is excluded from Him.
When something has a definition, and is distinguished by certain
characteristics, that same definition will exclude form it things that
are outside of that definition. But because Hashem has no definition
at all, nothing is excluded from Him. Therefore, He knows everything
and can do anything. All this is because God is not defined by any
specific definitions, therefore, everything comes from Him.

As to the point that saying something is undefined is defining it, we have already dealt with this in our theology (and this very much is right-brain stuff):

The Rebbe Rashab explains that indeed, He is so undefined, that even calling Him "undefined" is not correct, because that would be a limit, so the truth is beyond words:
language itself is inadequate to describe Him, so even calling Him undefined is insufficient, and our understanding of it is completely impossible
the only reason we can even say this is because of the one thing we can understand about it, like the Maharal said: Hashem's lack of definition means He can be and do and know anything and everything - nothing is excluded. We are given this gift to a small, finite extent: as people, we can be whatever and whoever we want to be.

His problem is that he is stuck with objectivism, which is a form of materialism - all that exists is only what we can see. He demonstrates this in his next point
God existing is arbitrary
This is also a false witness. Firstly, He is not arbitrary; as we teach in our first law of Mishnah Torah, God is defined as the original reality from which all other reality gets its existence from. This is the exact opposite of arbitrary.
Secondly, there are manifold claims of His existence. He may think that all those claims are wrong, but bear in mind nobody is claiming there are goblins on venus.
Thirdly, the idea that rational thinkers shouldn't entertain arbitrary claims, otherwise they are being irrational, is not a good argument. Until something is known, it won't be discovered until someone entertains the possibility of its existence. People who refuse to do that are mostly just doing it out of fear - they don't want to make a mistake and "be fooled" or "look stupid".
Fourth, the fact that everything is fixed, has laws, and all the assumptions that go into his objectivist worldview, are also arbitrary! Why should laws not change? Why should the world operate logically? We are thankful it does, but the very fact that we can conceive of "tohu", pure chaos, means that order is arbitrary.

There is much more to say but it is exhausting. The final answer, the "forest", the tl;dr, is that Torah doesn't assume all is composed of finite, concrete, identifiable entities (the basic premise of his worldview), and he does, so we disagree on the basics. All other arguments are "trees" and it is very tiresome wading through them, with people who can't see the forest for the trees.
If someone is genuinely agnostic, and wants to honestly explore God's existence, and wants to tackle it seriously; philosophically, and theologically, I would recommend Rambam's Moreh Nevuchim (english), Gevurot Hashem as quoted above by the Maharal (hebrew), and Derech Mitzvotecha Haamanut Elokut (english), immediately followed by Achdut Hashem (hebrew as of yet). I would also be happy to make more recommendations if someone wishes to ask in the comments.
Best is to not engage. Someone who is making an assumption and using it as a logical argument is not worth arguing with - they are either foolish, cynical or outright dishonest. They are very unlikely to hear you and this answer is purely for those who are not stuck in assumptions and wish to learn some Torah theology.

Your last paragraph reminded me:  it says in Pirkei Avos:  know what to answer to an Apikoros, and someone (Rabbi Gavin Nitsun?) once told me know what to answer but don’t necessarily answer

First, the law of identity states that each thing is identical with itself. G-d is identical with G-d. The speaker in the video twists the application of the law by stating that everything in this world is finite, and any action of G-d in this world is finite, therefore a finite collection of finite things should be representative of what G-d is. This way god is identified with nature, which actually was done by Hitler and his national socialist philosophers. The problem is that in Judaism G-d does not live inside the universe. As we state in Koheles 1:9:

Only that shall happen Which has happened, Only that occur Which has occurred; There is nothing new Beneath the sun!

Yes, there is nothing new beneath or under the sun, i.e. inside the universe (i.e. finite dimensional). But from G-d who is outside the universe, i.e. from "above the sun", we do get novelty - prophesy, prophetic visions, and any kind of novel ideas. We believe not only in the infinite and omnipotent G-d, but also that He will give us infinite reward for our mitzvos.
Second, the existence of "god who can change laws of nature at a whim, negates any need to know laws of science", which is nonsense. Such a point is also not applicable to Judaism. G-d does not change anything at a whim. The miracles defying natural laws were designed from the 6 days of creation (see Pirkei Avos 5:6 for example). In fact the verse in Tehilim 93:1 clearly states that G-d is not changing any natural laws at a whim:

The LORD is king, He is robed in grandeur; the LORD is robed, He is girded with strength. The world stands firm; it cannot be shaken.

Basically, the speaker invents a false premise and uses it as a pretext to defy the "competing ideology" by using 2 false witnesses. That's a totally marxist way of doing things.

Might be interesting to consider the Rambam on this in MN 2

@RabbiKaii it seems to be a good framework against objectivism. I heard though that Jewish philosophy is light ways ahead. Did you see L. E. Goodman "God of Abraham"? https://www.amazon.com/God-Abraham-Lenn-Evan-Goodman/dp/0195083121. I am postponing looking at all that because it's not my training, but could be worthwhile.

No I haven't heard of it but I can categorically say that Judaism's theology is light years ahead of modern atheistic ideas. The very fact that, routinely their arguments are dealt with in a 800 year old book of ours is telling, and it's very often clear that they have a "meme" version of religion in their head, and apply it to both Christianity and Judaism (and our philosophy is already way ahead of Christianity's, which relies much more on faith than reason). Note though that objectivism is very much opposed to marxism

@RabbiKaii that's because the atheists  are simply recycling ancient greeks. Like evolution theory coming from Anaximander. They try to be classical.

"The miracles defying natural laws were designed from the 6 days of creation" ... even if one takes the Rambam's later expressed interventionist view (i.e. that miracles are indeed a violation of the natural order) that does not mean that the pursuit of science is pointless or absurd (quite the contrary). The operative principles are still עולם כמנהגו הולך (the world continually operates according to its natural order) and אין סומכין על הנס (we do not rely on miracles) such that the basic epistemological premises of scientific advance and study are not disrupted.

There is evidence for God. Many people have claimed to have interacted with him.
Even if something cannot be demonstrated true or false, one can still reasonably believe in it due to 1) Occam's Razor or 2) it is comforting/pleasurable to do so.
You don't appreciate community input because you had to specify that you believe in God. You actually fear community input and will probably crumble emotionally if it calls you a heretic.

I’m not a heretic, nor am I afraid of being accused of one. I’ve recently however been thinking about secular philosophy and I like others who can strengthen my existing emunah

That argument is actually put forth more often by Christians and Pagans than by Jews. It can hardly be considered an argument at all. Sure, it might be “comforting”, but it’s not proof of anything. Now, something like Rav Mordechai Eliyahu praying to Hashem and then asking the Chida to fix his own bones—that’s a unique claim. But even that isn’t empirical.
